# MOSFET is getting very hot at high frequency PWM

Tags: mosfet, inductance, high-frequency

I want to drive a Litz wire coil at 250 kHz. I chose Arduino initially and then replaced it with NE555, but the Arduino or NE555 is generating 250 kHz, which is fed in a Litz coil to turn on some LED lights wirelessly like the following:

[image]

My schematic is like this:

[image: source: https://www.instructables.com/Mosfet-Qith-Arduino-IRFZ44N-IRLZ44N-IRF530N/]

The other difference with the above diagram is that:

1. I'm using a coil instead of the motor:

[image: source: https://www.uchidg.com/sale-10803707-copper-wire-wireless-charging-coil-70-humidity-for-wearable-device.html]

2. I'm using IRFZ44N instead.
3. I've also put a 10nF capacitor in parallel with the coil which dramatically increases the brightness of the lights above the coil.
4. No diodes are there with the coil.

The problem is that with the configuration given above, the MOSFET is getting very hot even with a fat heatsink.

I've also used NE555 instead of the Arduino and supplied 9V to the Gate of the IRFZ44N MOSFET, but it's still getting massively hot and the circuit consumes about an amp of current.

When the source voltage, however, is under 3 volts it's very cool. But I'm wondering for what reason 3 volts are cool, but 4 is burning hot.

I don't have an oscilloscope, but I have got a meter than can measure frequency and duty cycle.
The spooky part is that when I generate 50 kHz on NE555 or Arduino side, the MOSFET is still outputting 450 kHz at a 30% duty cycle. Regardless of 52% from NE555. Increasing the frequency to 100KHz on NE555 gave me 1MHz reading on the MOSFET drain.

Also, if I disconnect the coil, and only connect the frequency meter, it doesn't generate any output at all. The MOSFET by itself is all good and tried with 2 MOSFETS.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT
Here's the schematic with arduino:

[image: Arduino Schematic]

The code is just:

```
#define PIN1 3

// The sweet spot
#define FREQUENCY 2

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN1, OUTPUT);

  while (true) {
    digitalWrite(PIN1, HIGH) ;
    delayMicroseconds(FREQUENCY) ;
    digitalWrite(PIN1, LOW) ;
    delayMicroseconds(FREQUENCY) ;
  }
}
```

Schematic with NE555
[image]

Comment: You say you put a capacitor in _series_ with the coil, but that would block the DC path from the power supply to the FET drain, and nothing would work.  What did you really do?  Please _edit your question_ with this information, so that it is complete.  It would probably be best if you include the capacitor in your Muntzing diagram -- or better yet, give us an actual schematic.

Comment: Please draw a proper schematic circuit and don't rely on circuit-board and component images because, they don't make any sense. A circuit please. Also link the LED modules you are using.

Comment: Oops, a mistake, it's in parallel!

Comment: You really need a proper driver to switch the MOSFET on and off quickly, especially over 10 KHz or so. And you really need to get an oscilloscope to have any hope of properly troubleshooting and successfully building any serious electronics project.

Comment: Definitely use a MOSFET driver. If you can't do that, use a smaller MOSFET, which will have lower capacitances and require less drive to switch it (my favorite for small but reasonable power MOSFETs is the Siliconix (now Vishay Siliconix) Si2318). How much current are you switching through this coil?

Comment: You also *should* have a diode in antiparallel with the coil. I missed that before, but that may well be your biggest problem--your IRFZ44N is repeatedly being driven to avalanche by the coil inductance. If that makes your coil turn off too slow, put a resistor in series with the diode, but you *need* to have that diode there.

Comment: Ah, now that you have the schematic, that capacitor can *sort of* act as a snubber, if you're doing resonant switching. That might be hard with an arduino though.

Comment: When I directly use a diode with reverse polarity, the output is significantly lesser. Any idea what should the resistor value be when connected in series with the diode?

Comment: @Hearth it still goes burning hot without the capacitor

Comment: @S.Goswami Without the capacitor you're making things worse. You need the capacitor, perhaps in series with a resistor, or a diode and resistor.

Comment: How hot *is* burning hot anyway? It would be perfectly fine (though in need of some optimization) if it got to like 60 °C (more than enough to burn you if you touch it); the problem is when it gets beyond its rated temperature, usually 125 °C.

Comment: The part where you still get 450 kHz regardless of the excitation frequency is because your capacitor and inductor form a resonant circuit, which presumably resonates at close to 450 kHz.

Comment: @Hearth at 5 volts it's pretty hot, with a big heatsink it's still untouchable, and slowly it becomes so hot that you can smell heat from it (probably goes over 100 C).

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope to view the drain waveform? I think you will find either the voltage changes suddenly (cap charged by force as MOSFET turns on --> big dissipation) or overshoots heavily (no cap, inductor flyback as MOSFET turns off --> big dissipation). The resonant frequency must be matched for this to work, actually it must be a bit lower which gets into class E operation.

Comment: I don't have an oscilloscope unfortunately.

BTW, if I put a diode parallel to the coil (so cathode connects to +ve), when: (1) circuit is off, it's a short circuit. (2) circuit is on the LED dims significantly.

Comment: Again, with a resistor with the diode, the light doesn't drop much, resistor gets very hot, frequency is reduced, MOSFET isn't blazing hot. I'll confirm again.

Comment: @Hearth no, a diode is not needed and is, in fact, counter productive.

Comment: @S.Goswami you need a source resistor of circa 4.7 ohm and, you need to drive the gate with about 4 or 5 volts DC superimposed with a lowish amplitude signal. You can't just hit it with a logic signal and hope for the best or you'll get tremendous heating. I've designed various sinewave oscillator using a parallel LC tank (for metal detectors) and you need to drive it with care. I'll also add that the IRFZ44 MOSFET is not a great device for this application. On the other hand the older IRFZ14 is but has a lower voltage rating.

Comment: an irlZ44n would probably run a lot cooler at that frequency. It's lower gate voltage means lower on resistance, but it also has more gate capacitance, which (practically) leads to switching costs as the transitions are slower. A poor-mans gate driver can be made from logic level converters, a logic IC like a hex Schmidt trigger, or just a darlington-eque helper signal transistor, like a 2n2222, which inverts but that doesn't matter for you. If nothing else, add a 5-10k gate pulldown to lower switch-off waste.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [IRFZ44N](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/17807/PHILIPS/IRFZ44N.html) is not well suited to logic level drive. You should get a MOSFET with a much lower gate threshold voltage to get the lowest ON resistance. But you also need to drive it with more current than an Arduino output can provide. Here is a simple gate driver that should improve things, although a dedicated driver will work even better.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOMs0S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: 100 kHz PWM Drive]

I also ran this simulation with an IRFZ44, and directly from the 5V PWM signal with 200 ohm series resistance (simulating Arduino GPIO with 25 mA maximum drive), and it is clear that the MOSFET is not properly driven for efficient switching, causing a lot of heating:

[image: 100 kHz PWM Arduino Direct (200 ohm)]

Comment: I've also added an inductor and 10nF capacitor to the 55NF06L, and all looks good in simulation. In real life, however, I can't find a 55NF06L anywhere in this country, I've to import it for a huge cost. I've got one FQP50N06 though, do you think that'll work?

Comment: That device has similar gate threshold (2-4V) to that of your IRFZ44N. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/308/1/FQP50N06_D-1810007.pdf You should get a logic level device such as https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/Infineon_IRLZ44N_DataSheet_v01_01_EN-1732914.pdf

Answer (score 9):

> ...generating 250 kHz, which is fed in a Litz coil to turn on some LED lights wirelessly...

This is not the same as driving a dc motor. A motor requires an average dc current to maintain the torque applied to the rotor.

To light the LEDs wirelessly, the Litz coil must have an ac current with zero average dc. Without the capacitor in parallel with the coil, an average dc current will will raise the FET drain voltage to breakover, thus causing excessive heating.

Using a diode across the coil will protect the FET, but will maintain the dc current current in the coil. The dc magnetic field will not cross to the receiving coil.

> I've also put a 10nF capacitor in parallel with the coil which dramatically increases the brightness of the lights above the coil.

I speculate that the capacitor is resonating with the coil as Hearth mentioned in a comment. This creates a sinusoidal current in the coil. This ac current will easily cross to the receiving coil to brighten the lights. Unfortunately, when the FET turns on, the capacitor acts as a short, so the drain current will approach \$5/R_{DSon}\$ amps, causing heating.

This reminds me of the 455KHz IF stages in the AM super-het receivers. The collectors of the BJTs were connected to a tap on the coil of a tank circuit that resonated at 455KHz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5kFaU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For this purpose the tank resonates at your chosen 250KHz. The tank is pulsed with short pulses at the resonant frequency. Synchronizing to the resonant frequency allows one short pulse to be applied every cycle. The tap is chosen to minimize the stress on the FET. Some protection may be required for the FET if the inductive kick is too high.

The only other way to lower the drive dissipation and maintain zero dc current in the coil is through a full bridge delivering sinusoidal pwm to the coil.

I have not tested this myself, but if a single transistor drive is desirable this approach is worth investigating.

As others have mentioned a better selection for the FET is required.

Very interesting (+1).

Comments welcome.

Answer (score 3):

When the MOSFET turns on, it connects the power supply directly to the capacitor. That results in an inrush of current as the power supply charges the capacitor. That current is so high that there is a high voltage drop across the MOSFET. That high current times that high voltage is equal to high power. That's what's mostly heating the MOSFET.

Remove that capacitor across the load. That will reduce the heating.

---

If the MOSFET still gets hot, it's because of switching losses because the MOSFET is not turned on and off fast enough. That's because the 555 cannot provide the high current that the MOSFET gate requires to turn on rapidly.

Add a buffer (a gate driver) between the 555 and the MOSFET.

---

Finally, build the circuit carefully, not mid-air:

- Use a common ground point, and ideally a ground plane
- Use a large capacitor across the supply rails
- Use short wires to the gate driver

Comment: I've reproduced the issue without any capacitor connected to the MOSFET at all